# How to query two collections at the same time?

Tags: mongodb, join, non-relational-database

I am using MongoDB and I ended up with two Collections (unintentionally).

The first Collection (sample) has 100 million records (Tweets) with the following structure:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("515af34297c2f607b822a54b"),
"text" : "bla bla ",
"id" : NumberLong("314965680476803072"),
"user" : 
       {
        "screen_name" : "TheFroooggie",
        "time_zone" : "Amsterdam",
       },
}
```

The second Collection (users) with 30 Million records of unique users from the tweet collection and it looks like this

```
{ "_id" : "000000_n", "target" : 1, "value" : { "count" : 5 } }
```

where the _id in the users collection is the user.screen_name from the tweets collection, the target is their status (spammer or not) and finally the value.count is the number a user appeared in our first  collection (sample) collection (e.g. number of captured tweets)

Now I'd like to make the following query:

I'd like to return all the documents from the sample collection (tweets) where the user has the target value = 1

In other words, I want to return all the tweets of all the spammers for example.

Comment: Queries only can act on one collection at a time. There are no joins. Ther are some frameworks that can make it seem like there are joins, but it's an illusion and many queries are in fact made. There are a lot of questions/answers on StackOverflow about this.

Comment: Thanks WiredPrairie for your comment. I did explore some of the solutions address in StackOverflow, many weren't efficient enough to accommodate the number of records I have or they did not suite my needs. I wonder if it is straightforward to actually have a third collection with the 'users' (the second collection) and their tweets as sub-documents. However, I'd need an efficient implementation to finish this in a reasonable time and I'd appreciate any help as a I am a beginner in this non-relational world

Comment: you do not want to embed tweets into user documents.  what is the problem with making two queries here?  If things are properly indexed it would be reasonably fast (certainly faster than maintaining a third collection).  If it's critical to do it in one query you can denormalize the target field into the tweets collection user subdocument and then have a batch job which updates them when someone is "reclassified".

Comment: Yes, I totally agree, the problem of embedding tweets as sub-document would actually grow unbounded. How would the two queries look like ? I mean if I query the users database for users with target 1 I'd get an iterator with part of the results, how would I pass it to the second query to get their tweets ?. Btw I apologies in advanced if the answer is trivial, I am very new to this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you receive the tweets you could upsert them into a collection.  Using the author information as the key in the "query" document portion of the update.  The update document could utilize the `$addToSet` operator to put the tweet into a tweets array.  You'll end up with a collection that has the author and an array of tweets.  You can then do your spammer classification for each author and have their associated tweets.

So, you would end up doing something like this:

```
db.samples.update({"author":"joe"},{$addToSet:{"tweets":{"tweet_id":2}}},{upsert:true})
```

This approach does have the likely drawback of growing the document past its initially allocated size on disk which means it would be moved and expanded on disk. You would likely incur some penalty for index updating as well.

You could also take an approach of storing a spam rating with each tweet document and later pulling those based on user id.

As others have pointed out, there is nothing wrong with setting up the appropriate indexes and using a cursor to loop through your users pulling their tweets.

The approach you choose should be based on your intended access pattern. It sounds like you are in a good place where you can experiment with several different possible solutions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that signatures and signoffs aren't recommended on either questions or answers. :-)

Comment: This is a very poor schema for performance - each user document would grow unbounded, plus to get the latest tweet from someone you would have to query across the entire subset of their tweets.  There is nothing inherently wrong with having two collections the way the OP does, they just need to have a strategy for queries that have to access information from both (either two queries or denormalize some of the information).